# Which airline is legally responsible for undue charges in a multi-stop flight booking

Tags: international, fees, customer-service

I booked a multi-stop international flight from Qatar airways website, and the receipt clearly states that 1 piece of checked-in baggage is included in the price. In fact, for each leg separately it shows 1 piece included. Now the first leg is operated by Alaska Airlines, and the rest by Qatar themselves. Upon check-in, Alaska staff made me pay for the baggage saying that they have no agreement with Qatar. I showed them my receipt and tried to explain that the receipt shows all services I am entitled to for the price I paid, but they told me I won't fly with my baggage if I don't pay. They told me to figure this out with Qatar.

I sent a formal enquiry to Qatar regarding this, to which they answered that they cannot issue a refund for fees they did not charge, and sent me back to Alaska.

**Question:** Which of the two airlines is responsible for this error, and how should I approach this to receive a refund?

My reasoning tells me that my purchase was with Qatar, and I have paid them for services I haven't received, since I received those services independently from Alaska and paid for them (1 pc checked-in baggage). But I would appreciate a more knowledgeable opinion.

Thank you.

Comment: Under which countries law was the ticket issued? Under your contract, where and how are disputes to be resolved?

Comment: According to the Qatar website, "The Terms of Use of this Website shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of the State of Qatar. The Qatari courts shall have non-exclusive jurisdiction to adjudicate any disputes, which may arise as a result."